# parse a particular record from json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have following json object

```
       var testObj = {
        "CompanyA": [
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Produce", "revenue": { "2022": 130143, "2021": 172122, "2020": 103716 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "France" ], "productLine": "Clothing", "revenue": { "2022": 85693, "2021": 91790, "2020": 77650 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "France" ], "productLine": "Electronics", "revenue": { "2022": 121987, "2021": 62435, "2020": 65834 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Produce", "revenue": { "2022": 130143, "2021": 107447, "2020": 145543 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Clothing", "revenue": { "2022": 77903, "2021": 97139, "2020": 110346 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "Germany" ], "productLine": "Electronics", "revenue": { "2022": 110897, "2021": 155282, "2020": 128696 } },
            { "geography": [ "South America", "Brazil" ], "productLine": "Clothing", "revenue": { "2022": 66217, "2021": 55798, "2020": 66643 } },
            { "geography": [ "South America", "Brazil" ], "productLine": "Electronics", "revenue": { "2022": 94262, "2021": 100560, "2020": 56272 } }
          ],
          "CompanyB": [
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "United Kingdom" ], "productLine": "Produce", "revenue": { "2022": 281110, "2021": 242965, "2020": 221863 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "United Kingdom" ], "productLine": "Clothing", "revenue": { "2022": 168270, "2021": 121161, "2020": 60919 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "United Kingdom" ], "productLine": "Electronics", "revenue": { "2022": 239537, "2021": 131959, "2020": 97047 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "Ireland" ], "productLine": "Produce", "revenue": { "2022": 74963, "2021": 43406, "2020": 54623 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "Ireland" ], "productLine": "Clothing", "revenue": { "2022": 44872, "2021": 24797, "2020": 16010 } },
            { "geography": [ "Europe", "Ireland" ], "productLine": "Electronics", "revenue": { "2022": 63877, "2021": 94185, "2020": 87098 } }
          ],
         .........
       };
```

There are three dropdowns in my page like Company, Geography(CountryName2nd element) and ProductLine...

Based on the selected dropdown values i need to pick up the revenue ..

I was able to capture the **companyname**, **Geography(countryName)** and **productLine** chosen by user but struggling to get to that particular revenue...

I can get the revenue like this

```
console.log(testObj[company][1].revenue);
```

but here i am not sure of the particular record because i need to choose based on country and productLine

I got the solution for this. But i want to know whats is the best way of parsing the json objects... is it reconstructing according to our needs or looping through the json object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter matching objects like this

```
var company = "CompanyA";
var country = "Germany";
var productLine = "Produce";

var res = testObj[company].filter(function(el){
  return el.geography[1] == country && productLine == el.productLine;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: hi neo, i tried your answer its working... can you tell me why did you use el.geography[1] with index 1...... just want to know....

Comment: geography[1] is country (`["Europe", "Germany"][1] === "Germany"`) which looks enough to check if two geography arrays are equal

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to loop through the array until you find the one that matches:

```
var companyArr = testObj[company];
for(var i = 0; i < companyArr.length; i++){
    if(companyArr[i].geography[1] == country && companyArr[i].productLine == productLine)
        break;
}

if(i < companyArr.length){ // Found a match
    console.log(companyArr[i]); // Log the matching object
}
```

Note if restructuring your json is an option then you could avoid loops altogether and just do something like:

```
testObj[company][country][productLine].revenue
```

Comment: hello thanks for reply... i tried your solution it gave me an error "Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

Comment: i presume if(companyArr.geography[1] should be if(companyArr.geography[i]

Comment: i tried it as well it tells me "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: should be `companyArr[i].geography[1]`, `companyArr[i].productLine`